# Potts model 1st order transitions and the sensitivity of $q_c=4$ to microscopic details

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, spin-models

The ferromagnetic $q$-state [Potts model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potts_model) describes a lattice of classical spins $\sigma=\{1,2,...,q\}$ and has Hamiltonian with nearest-neighbor interactions

$$
H = -\sum_{<ij>} \delta_{\sigma_i, \sigma_j}
$$

I'll be imagining a $2$d square lattice throughout the following. At a finite temperature, the model above is known for having continuous phase transitions for $q\leq q_c$ and suffering from first-order phase transitions for $q>q_c$, where $q_c=4$.

I have always assumed that this $q_c$ was in some senses a universal quantity -- that is, if I were to perturb $H$ above by some translationally-invariant extensive sum of local operators that respects the symmetries of the model and does not induce frustration, $q_c$ for that model would be $4$ as well.

Is this true? For example, if I perturb by $$-\lambda \sum_{i,j \text{ next-nearest-neighbors}}\delta_{\sigma_i, \sigma_j}$$  for $\lambda>0$, is $q_c$ still $4$?

---

Below I give an explanation for my motivation which is relevant but not necessary for understanding my question.

A friend pointed to me the following [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/NHrcyDAVFq8?list=PLx5f8IelFRgHYWO-sgYSE5DD8K4AL15cG&t=3862), and I transcribe the following relevant question and answer:

> Q: [...] In the $q=3$-state Potts model, for the nearest neighbor
> interaction you have a second order transition, but if you allow your
> range to go a little longer, you'll get a first order transition [...]
>
> A: [...] We are used to talking about universality, and it's taken for
> granted that at short distances, various parameters don't affect the
> critical behavior. For example, whether [a coupling] is
> nearest-neighbor or not. In the case of $q$-state Potts, that's not
> the case. The fact that $q=4$ is the magic place does depend on
> planarity. It's known you lose the special nature of $q=4$ when you
> spread interactions, and eventually the relevant quantity to look at
> is the mean field calculation [..]

To me, this discussion was surprising and I am not sure how to interpret it. It appears to be saying that $q_c$ is a detailed function of microscopic details and is not universal, but I'm not sure that I believe that.

One way to interpret this would be that the question-asker was referring to the addition of long-range (i.e. power-law decaying) interactions, which would not be inconsistent with my belief in the universality of $q_c$ on the addition of local, translationally-invariant, symmetry-respecting, non-frustrating interactions. I agree that $q_c$ can change on the addition of long-range interactions -- a sufficiently long-range power-law interaction will induce mean-field behavior with $q_c=2$, and mean-field behavior is indeed mentioned by the answerer. However, there a couple points against this interpretation. The question-asker said "if you allow your range to go a little longer" in a way that seemed to me to be pointing towards adding short-ranged interactions like next-nearest neighbor interactions. Second, the answerer seemed to be distinguishing the behavior of $q$ in the $q$-state Potts model from other universal quantities in other models, but sufficiently-long-range interactions can affect all universal quantities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Michael is perfectly correct in his answer in the video you linked. It is indeed expected that the value $q_c=4$ is specific to the **planar** Potts model (that is, the Potts model on a planar graph with nearest-neighbor interactions). Although this has not been proved in general, there are rigorous results in this direction. Let me mention the two most relevant to your question.

- First, there is the paper [Journal of Statistical Physics 126, 3 (2007) pages 507-583](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10955-006-9230-8). In this paper, the authors consider a class of **finite-range** ferromagnetic $q$-states Potts model on $\mathbb{Z}^d$ and prove that the transition is of first order for any $d\geq 2$ and $q\geq 3$ once the range is taken large enough (but still finite!). In particular, $q_c=2$ in all cases (since it is known that the transition in the short-range Ising model is always continuous).
- Another relevant work is [Communications in Mathematical Physics 292 No 2 303–341 (2009)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00220-009-0847-8). In this paper, the autor considers a two-dimensional ferromagnetic $3$-states Potts model with **exponentially decaying** interactions and proves that, again, the behavior of the model is approximated by that of the mean-field model and uses this to conclude that $q_c=2$ in dimension $2$ in this model as well.

In both papers, the approach is to show that their model becomes close enough (in a strong sense) to the mean-field Potts model once the interaction range is sufficiently large (in the first case), or the rate of exponential decay sufficiently slow (in the second case). It is of course easy to see that $q_c=2$ in the mean-field model.

Note also that the fact that, in both works, it was necessary to take a large enough range (or slow enough exponential decay) of the interaction is expected to be only a technical issue, originating from the need to compare with the mean-field model. What is expected is that the relevant feature of the model required to have $q_c=4$ in two dimensions is planarity. In particular, the conjecture is indeed that adding a next-nearest neighbor (translation invariant, ferromagnetic) interaction to your nearest neighbor model should change $q_c$ from $4$ to $2$. This has not yet been proved, unfortunately.

Comment: This is quite eye-opening! I find the finite-range models particularly notable. It looks like there was a [numerical paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.08831) on the finite range models that saw clear first-order behavior on including all interactions within a radius including 80 spins in $q=3$. They didn't see first-order behavior for shorter range than that, but maybe that's because they can only probe finite sizes?

Comment: To confirm, arbitrarily weak disturbing of planarity, like adding next-nearest neighbor interactions with a arbitrarily weak coupling constant relative to the vanilla nearest neighbor interaction, is conjectured to bring $q_c$ down to $2$?

Comment: Yes, that's the form of the conjecture I know of. But I am not sure that the latter is based on any solid heuristics (at least, I don't know any). So it is certainly conceivable that only a large enough range makes the transition first order. But I would find that even more surprising than observing an atypical behavior of planar models (since I am aware of other peculiarities of planar models, although none as obvious as the order of the transition).

Comment: Thanks again. I guess I have in mind roughly that some models are stable to adding vacancies, but add enough density of vacancies and they become first-order (like Ising model in Blume-Capel form), so that in analogy there might be some threshold range or threshold relative strength before the transition becomes first order (I think this is a rough argument made in the numerical paper above). That's a good point that planar models have many special properties -- I hadn't realized that, and I think then it sounds plausible that small violations of planarity can then lead to big changes.